# CSS: Combine Texture and Color

Tags: html, css

someone how to combine Texture use as background-image and Background-color above that texture ?

**Here the texture :**

[image: Texture alone]

**I want my body background page to be like this :**

[image]

I'm struggling with backroung-image and background-color : http://jsfiddle.net/87K72/

```
body{
  background: #6DB3F2 url('http://s13.postimg.org/j0qiscsw3/cream.png');
 }
```

Comment: Apply the background image to your `html` tag, apply the background color to your `body` tag and make sure it takes the whole page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an overlay div with an alpha channel on top of your body but under your other elements.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/87K72/1/)**

```
<h1>I want blue color above my texture</h1>
<div id="cover"></div>
body {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/oslRB.png');
}
h1{
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
#cover {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background-color:rgba(109,179,242,0.5);
    z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know about the top/left/bottom/right = 0 trick to get a stretched div across the whole viewport. Nice!

Comment: With pseudo elements the #cover could be easily avoided.

Comment: @Rollyng: This solution doesn't work with pages that allow scrolling down: http://jsfiddle.net/87K72/4/

Comment: @SimonSteinberger - just change `position:absolute;` to `position:fixed;`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your [texture here](http://s13.postimg.org/j0qiscsw3/cream.png) lacks an alpha channel. It's not semi-transparent, it's really white.

Comment: You was the first and you was right !! I take it here for your knowledge http://subtlepatterns.com/

Comment: Check the @j08691 solution there is a nice trick(must-know) Which works despite the value of transparency

Comment: Yeah, it's a nice trick, but it's basically the same idea of having a semi-transparent layer on top of another one. This time the color layer is on top. The problem with that approach is that you have to tweak the color and the the alpha value to have it just right, because making it semi-transparent will make it fade a little. If you work with a designer or if you need to respect a fixed color chart, it's better to work with the color codes as they are provided.

Comment: @Rollyng Sorry, but I still not see whats the point of using z-index to such thing. Just use a png with alpha channel like Miklos suggests or :after with opacity in the image. And yes, use a color as overlay layer with opacity is a problem to kept the exact reference.

Comment: @loops, i didn't use z-index. About alpha channel you're right, that clean solution. Thks you both

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a semi transparent background texture for that; then your CSS directive will do the trick:

HTML:

```
<h1>I want blue color above my texture</h1>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: #6DB3F2  url('http://wizzley.com/static/img/bg/texture8.png');
}
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/87K72/3/

Comment: Check the @j08691 solution there is a nice trick(must-know) Which works despite the value of transparency

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of css opacity to do this.

Create two divs - one for the color, and one for the texture:

HTML:

```
<div class="texture-color">
    <div class="texture">
        <h1> I want blue color above my texture</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.texture,.texture-color {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0; } 

.texture { 
    background: #6DB3F2 url('http://s13.postimg.org/j0qiscsw3/cream.png'); 
    opacity: 0.8; }

.texture-color { 
    background-color: cyan;  }
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a37ep/)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/uyrPA/3/

```
body {
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    background: green;
}


body:after{
    content : "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/oslRB.png) repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height:  100%;
    opacity : 0.5;
}

h1{
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
```

Comment: It should be "position: fixed" to make this work with pages that needs to be scrolled down. Additionally, it's a bit tedious to set the correct z-index for all elements that should appear above the color-layer.