# Combining Color and Texture with CSS - With Font Above Texture

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

How can I add a texture over top a solid color background using the pseudo `:after` element, while keeping the font on top of the texture?  Such as that used on the [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/) website.

Using the Font Awesome website and [CSS: Combine Texture and Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18105833/css-combine-texture-and-color) as references I have successfully overlaid the texture onto my background color, but my font appears *under* the texture as well.

Here is a JSFiddle of my current code: http://jsfiddle.net/EvilClosetMonkey/xuBbq/

I've tried several tweaks, looking over multiple similar effects, but I have not tracked down what I am missing.

How can I bring the font "above" the texture?

**Solution:**

Taking @JoshC's answer below I added the following CSS, so all contents (not just `h1`) appear above the texture.

```
.jumbotron .container
{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply add a `z-index` to the `h1` element. This would require the element to be positioned; therefore add `position:relative` too:

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WaVt4/)

```
.jumbotron h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 100px;
    text-shadow: 4px 3px 0 #df4566, 9px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Works great, thank you!  I made a slight change to your suggestion and included it in my question above (for future posterity).  I will accept answer in 5-minutes, when system lets me. :)